# sqlite C api how to figure out what tables have foreign keys?

Tags: sqlite

Using the C API, I don't see a way to determine the foreign key constraints for a named table?

Given this example:

```
CREATE TABLE artist(
  artistid    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  artistname  TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE track(
  trackid     INTEGER,
  trackname   TEXT, 
  trackartist INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY(trackartist) REFERENCES artist(artistid)
);
```

sqlite3_table_column_metadata() will tell you it's a primary key, autoincrement, etc. but how
do I get the foreign key constraints?

```
 FOREIGN KEY(trackartist) REFERENCES artist(artistid)
```

I want to be able to get a list back for table "track" that there are foreign keys back to table Artist column artistid?

I don't see an api to do this?  I need to do this programmaticlly upon opening the database, for purposes of aggregation.

Thanks.

After using PRAGMA foreign_key_list(Valuation);

I got back:

```
PRAGMA foreign_key_list(Valuation);
0|0|Stock|StockId|Id|NO ACTION|NO ACTION|NONE
```

I understand I need to split on the vertical bar, but what are the first two columns? 0|0 ?

Comment: Is this available? PRAGMA foreign_key_list(table-name);

Comment: I checked out the source, looks like the columns are: id, sequence, table, from, to, on_update, on_delete, match

Comment: The PRAGMA should produce a result set IIRC…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that (foreign) keys can consist of multiple columns, so it would not make sense to return this as column information.

To get information about a table's foreign keys, use this:

> [**PRAGMA foreign_key_list(***table-name***);**](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_key_list)
>
> This pragma returns one row for each [foreign key constraint](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) created by a REFERENCES clause in the CREATE TABLE statement of table "table-name".

Comment: I tried this and got back:  PRAGMA foreign_key_list(Valuation);
0|0|Stock|StockId|Id|NO ACTION|NO ACTION|NONE